# Sitecore shared fields getting cleared after deployment to other environments

Tags: multilingual, paas, tds

Sitecore 9.0 shared fields data was getting cleared after deployment in few environments including Production. In Pre production, the content is not cleared but can find this issue happening in lower environments and production after each deployment through Sitecore Pass.

The content is lost only in english language items and in Japanese language versions there is not content mismatch.

Comment: How do you deploy?  there is a known bug in Sitecore where Shared Fields get lost when installing packages and the items were originally created from a Branch Template. Only known fix is to install the package twice.

Comment: Hi Mark, Thank you for your reply. We deploy through Octopus. The shared fields where we lost content are from normal standard templates and not branch templates. We observed the mismatch of content during our last deployment to production and as a work around took a package of existing content before switching the environment.

Comment: @vasu do you know if any changes were made to the shared fields? As in was that select box checked or unchecked any time after initial deployment? I've heard of Sitecore issues related to this. It's the reason why Sitecore shows a warning message when changing that attribute on a field.

Comment: @Marcel, We did not notice any changes made to shared fields or templates with shared fields in recent time.  At present there is a Logo image field from template "A" (which was set as shared field) and few checkbox fields on template  "B". Both templates lost content when we tried to deploy to higher environments.